# Set LatLng location in constructor using latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am a beginner in Android programming. I want to create location objects, which contain doubles latitude and longitude, and the LatLng value is set using the latitude and longitude as input.

The problem I have now is that I create an object with latitude and longitude as parameters, but the LatLng appears to be null. (gives a runtime error when I want to use the LatLng value to set a marker). How do I set the LatLng value when creating an object with using the latitude and longitude as parameters?
This is my code:

```
public class Location {
    int id;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    LatLng location;

    public Location() {}

    public Location(int id, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    public Location(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLocation(LatLng location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public LatLng getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change to this will help you.

```
public class Location {
int id;
double latitude;
double longitude;
LatLng location;

public Location() {}

public Location(int id, double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.id = id;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;

}

public Location(double latitude, double longitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void setLocation(LatLng location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return this.latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return this.longitude;
}

public LatLng getLocation() {
    return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
}
}
```

Comment: get location using obj.getLocation()